# Can we use : Disable parallel apex testing option in production

Tags: unit-test

Can any one help me out? On opportunitylineitem there are triggers and apex classes. Now I have written another trigger on the same class.
All the test classes have above 75% code coverage. The organization's code coverage is 79% in Sandbox and organization's code coverage is 84%, but it throws an Error in production environment as:

```
Code Coverage Failure
Your organization's code coverage is 23%. You need at least 75% coverage to complete this deployment. Also, the following triggers have 0% code coverage. Each trigger must have at least 1% code coverage.

    editAfterApproval
    updatecopyPrice
    LockQuotes
    CopyTierPrices
    updateReadyForReview
    update10Kand2k
```

All have 75% code coverage

```
AccOppsegmentTestClass  validateAccOppsegment   System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, Populate_Extension: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Trigger.Populate_Extension: line 15, column 1: []
Stack Trace: Class.AccOppsegmentTestClass.validateAccOppsegment: line 19, column 1

BlxOppclonecontrollerTestClass  BlxOppClone System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, Populate_Extension: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Trigger.Populate_Extension: line 15, column 1: []
Stack Trace: Class.BlxOppclonecontrollerTestClass.BlxOppClone: line 15, column 1

Oli_multiple_Products_TestClass ValidateOlimultipleproducts System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, Populate_Extension: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Trigger.Populate_Extension: line 15, column 1: []
Stack Trace: Class.Oli_multiple_Products_TestClass.ValidateOlimultipleproducts: line 15, column 1

TestInvoiceController   Invoicemethodtest   System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 1000.00, Actual: 0.02
Stack Trace: Class.TestInvoiceController.Invoicemethodtest: line 105, column 1

TestInvoiceController   Invoicemethodtest1  System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 1000.00, Actual: 2.00
Stack Trace: Class.TestInvoiceController.Invoicemethodtest1: line 258, column 1

X10Kand2kTest   X10Kand2kTest   System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, field integrity exception: UnitPrice (only one of unit price or total price may be specified): [UnitPrice]
Stack Trace: Class.X10Kand2kTest.X10Kand2kTest: line 54, column 1
```

So Can I use this option in production.

> You can prevent receiving those errors by turning off parallel test execution in the Salesforce user interface:
>
> 1. From Setup, click Develop | Apex Test Execution | Options....
> 2. > 2.In the Apex Test Execution Options dialog, select Disable Parallel Apex Testing and than click OK.

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: pls add some more information. What error are you getting?  Which (and how many) test classes are you running? Sure, you can use this option in production. Not sure if it will solve your problem. Just give it a try!

Comment: @guy:I have added with the Error .Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: You've got a lot of errors in your system tests. So you need to find out if your new code is causing this, or if these are existing errors. When you run your test classes in production (without doing the deployment), do they run ok then?

Comment: @guy:All the test class went fine ,but at one test class method it throwed an Error as :System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW, unable to obtain exclusive access to this record: []
Stack Trace Class.TestInvoiceController.Invoicemethodtest: line 93, column 1

Comment: in that case you can Disable Parallel Testing on production. That's no problem. Only thing that will happen is that your tests will run slower.

Comment: Please update your first question rather than re-posting it. I can't see much difference, if there is any please update your question to highlight this.

Comment: @ Samuel De Rycke:In this post i had a query regarding the Disable parallel apex testing option in production.Since guy asked in the comment regarding the errors i have edited the query and added the errors.

Comment: Duplicate question not found :/